# displaying column names instead of data from psql terminal

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I connect to the remote ubuntu 20.04 computer from the terminal with ssh, connect to the database that I have installed on the postgres user, and I want to see the data in a column with psql commands. I am not displaying the data, but the columns as much as the number of data.

The codes I write:

```
SELECT 'Name' FROM "Restaurants";
```

The result:

[image]

How can I view the datas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'Name'` is a string constant, identifiers (column names) must be enclosed in double quotes (the same you did with the table name)

```
SELECT "Name" FROM "Restaurants";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Restaurants
-> You can view all column